# Logstash - Filebeat don't parse every line of an IIS Log File

Tags: elasticsearch, iis, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to parse IIS logs from a log file on the server, the grok filters are not the problem because i tried without it.

Logstash parse only half of the lines in the log file, for example :

The IIS Log file has events from 1:00 AM to 12:00 PM, but logstash only parses from 3:00 AM (for example) to 9:00 PM. The first and last event parsed are random, there is no order in the parsin.

Does anybody knows how to force logstash to parse every line of the log ?

Thank you for your help.

This is my Filebeat.yml

```
###################### Filebeat Configuration Example 


#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================

filebeat.prospectors:

- type: log

 enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - C:\IIS\new.log

    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*


#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  #path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: true

  # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
  reload.period: 30s

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: true

#============================== Kibana =====================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
#setup.kibana:

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
#output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["10.28.52.171:9200"]
  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:

  # The Logstash hosts

 hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

Comment: Does your IIS log files contain multiline entries ?